# How do I use text and a formula in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

`"Books Added in October 2020  " & "counta(A3:A)"`
This is not working.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome. 
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Please include a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct the syntax in your formula.

It should be

```
="Books Added in October 2020 " & counta(A3:A)
```

That is:  `= "some text here" & myformula`
Or maybe: `= "some text here" & myformula & "more text"`
Or even:  `= "some text here" & myformula & "more text" & another formula`